# Gradle: Excluding tags does not work from command line

Tags: gradle, automation, tags

I have in my build.gradle file the following section:

```
test {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', System.getProperty('env')
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'tag1', 'tag2'
        excludeTags
    }
}
```

When I need to run only tag1 I use the following command:

```
gradle clean test -DincludeTags='tag1' -DexcludeTags='tag2'
```

But anyway both tags are executed. What am I doing wrong?